# Does UNR (9.10) or eeebuntu have better support for Asus EeePC 1005HA?

Tags: eee-pc, ubuntu-netbook-remix, eeebuntu

I'm looking at what distribution to install on my new eeepc (1005HA) and I'm wondering whether Ubunut Netbook Remix (UNR) or eeebuntu is more suitable?

Specifically, I am looking for a base system that has the best balance between driver support, optimization and features to my netbook's make and model.  I intend to use this computer for hobby project development while on the train to work.

Comment: It's not an answerable question.  More information needed, like what you plan to do with the netbook and what you personally value in an OS.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a bit old, but I found this question while Googling for the same information.

I hope this helps, it is the best forum thread I've come across so far:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1370066

Comment: Thanks @Beredon, I've actually been using UNR since I posted this, and found it to be spectacular.  The only issue that I've found is in the poorly performing wireless driver.